# Formatting boxplots for scientific journal

Tags: r, plot

I'm publishing a paper in a scientific journal with some boxplots, I have two figures, and they have different numbers of boxplots on them.  I want the plot bars to be the same width.  I don't want to control the width of the entire plot, but of the bars.

Here's what I've got:

```
Clades<-c("C-A","C-A","C-A","C-A","C-A","C-A","C-A","C-A","C-A","C-B","C-B","C-B","C-B","C-B","C-B","C-B","C-B","C-C","C-C","C-C","C-C","C-C","C-C","C-C","C-C","C-D","C-D","C-D","C-D","C-D","C-D","C-D","C-D","G-A","G-A","G-A","G-A","G-A","G-A","G-A","G-A","G-A","G-A","G-A","G-B","G-B","G-B","G-B","G-B","G-B","G-B","G-B","G-B","G-B","G-C","G-C","G-C","G-C","G-C","G-C","G-C","G-D","G-D","G-D","G-D","G-D","G-D","G-D","G-D","G-D","G-D","G-D","G-E","G-E","G-E","G-E","G-E","G-E","G-E","G-E","G-E","G-E")
NoGClades<-c("C-A","C-A","C-A","C-A","C-A","C-A","C-A","C-A","C-A","C-B","C-B","C-B","C-B","C-B","C-B","C-B","C-B","C-C","C-C","C-C","C-C","C-C","C-C","C-C","C-C","C-D","C-D","C-D","C-D","C-D","C-D","C-D","C-D","G","G","G","G","G","G","G","G","G","G","G","G","G","G","G","G","G","G","G","G","G","G","G","G","G","G","G","G","G","G","G","G","G","G","G","G","G","G","G","G","G","G","G","G","G","G","G","G","G")
HapDiv<-c(12,23,12,34,12,34,12,34,12,115,123,12,34,45,123,3,23,13,156,14,5,14,14,11,12,12,34,12,34,12,115,123,12,34,45,123,3,23,12,23,12,12,23,12,123,12,34,45,12,34,12,12,34,12,13,156,14,5,12,34,45,115,123,12,14,14,11,34,12,34,12,34,123,3,23,12,23,12,12,13,156,14)

Haplotypes<-data.frame(Clades,NoGClades,HapDiv) # create data frame
plot(Haplotypes$Clades, Haplotypes$HapDiv, 
  xlab="Clade", ylab="Haplotype Diversity",
  main="Haplotype Diversity with Clades in G")
plot(Haplotypes$NoGClades, Haplotypes$HapDiv, 
  xlab="Clade", ylab="Haplotype Diversity",
  main="Haplotype Diversity with no Clades in G")
```

Because there are different numbers of bars - the individual bars are different widths in the two plots.  How do I control their width so it is exactly equal?

In general, I'd like to have a straightforward way to control the look of the boxplots, as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `ggplot2` to create the plot.

Change you data to the long format with `tidyr`:

```
library(tidyr)
dat <- gather(Haplotypes, variable, value, -HapDiv)
```

Rename the factor levels:

```
levels(dat$variable) <- c("Haplotype Diversity with Clades in G",
                          "Haplotype Diversity with no Clades in G")
```

Plot:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(dat, aes(x = value, y = HapDiv)) + 
  geom_boxplot() + 
  facet_grid(. ~ variable, scales = "free_x", space = "free_x") +
  xlab("Clade") +
  theme_bw()
```

[image]

Comment: `dat <- gather(Haplotypes, HapDiv)` 
Warning message:
attributes are not identical across measure variables; they will be dropped

Comment: @SteveT I updated the `gather` code. However, the warning message remains but is no problem in this case.